# Android: Как правильно хранить данные?

Tags: ооп, android, java

Здравствуйте!

Меня интересует такой вопрос: как правильно организовать хранение часто используемых данных? У меня есть 3 коллекции, данные которые они хранят используются для вывода нескольких ListView. Изначально я запихнул коллекции в статичные переменные в базовую активити и они были доступны отовсюду. Сейчас я переделал эту схему на выборку из базы, каждый раз когда эти данные требуются, и вот не пойму, правильно я сделал, или хранение в статических переменных это нормальная практика для подобных задач?

Comment: Глобальные переменные — зло, а статические переменные мало чем от них отличаются. Ну и в случае с android, это ещё и источник трудноуловимых NPE.

Comment: @falstaf - да, я это прекрасно понимаю, но как сделать по другому? каждый раз дергать данные из базы и прятать это за диалогом загрузки?

Comment: А в чём проблема передавать эти данные, например, в `Intent`'е, при запуске другой `Activity`?

Comment: У меня одна активити, после авторизации я попадаю на PreloaderActivity которая асинхронно тянет с сервера инфу и пишет её в базу, как все загрузки завершились, запускается уже MainActivity (после неё уже никаких запусков активити не будет), у неё реализован NavigationDrawer и переключаясь в меню запускаются разные фрагменты.

Comment: Ну хорошо. Но ведь есть `Fragment.setArguments()`.

Comment: Т.е. как запустилась MainActivity, вытаскиваем необходимые данные из базы и через `Fragment.setArguments()`? А когда запускается другой фрагмент, мы опять идем в базу, достаем данные и передаем их в другой фрагмент? Как-то так я понял вышесказанное...

Comment: Зачем данные заново доставать? Один ведь уже есть у вас, когда вы их достали в `MainActivity`. Вот и передавайте нужные фрагментам.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Глобальные переменные зло, если только с ними неправильно обращаться. По самой сути явления всегда есть переменные, которые должны быть глобальными - скажем хэндлер к БД (или если угодно хэндлер к DAO) - он по сути своей глобален - нравится это кому то или нет.

Идеальным местом для хранения таких глобальных вещей является объект [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html), который является естественным синглтоном для Android аппликации.

Надо декларировать в манифесте кастомный `Application` класс и "положить" туда свои глобальные переменные туда (обложив сеттерами/геттерами). `Application` практически везде доступен через `Activity.getApplication()`

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  private MyPreciousClass myPreciousObject;

  public MyPreciousClass getMyPreciousObject() {
     return this.myPreciousObject;
  }
}

//где в коде
MyApplication myApp=(MyApplication)this.getApplication();
myPreciousObject=myApp.getMyPreciousObject();
```

Comment: исправил - обожаю внимательных людей

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, действительно, в статических переменных лучше хранить только статические( константные ) значения, которые постоянны на протяжении всего RunTime`а. Раз вам необходимо
обращаться к данным отовсюду, я бы посоветовал вам создать свой класс для хранения информации, в котором будет инкапсулирована вся логика работы с данными: их хранение, изменение, чтение и генерация исключений в случае ошибок. Ну а экземпляр класса уже хранить в статической переменной в базовой Activity( или же даже можно выделить отдельный класс Data с хранением статических ссылок на объекты и прочие данные ).  Таким образом вы обезопасите свое приложение от ошибок, связанным со статикой.